# mysql doesn't separate between e and è

Tags: mysql, ucs2

There are two tables in mysql databse that use ucs2_slovenian_ci (that I can't change). How can I make sql that will recognize the differece between 'e' and 'è' and won't connect those rows with differet values?

```
SELECT tableA.value, tableB.value
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON (tableA.value = tableB.value)
```

doesn't work.Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could force a binary comparison:

```
SELECT tableA.value, tableB.value
FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableB ON tableA.value = BINARY tableB.value
```

Please have a look at the [binary operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html) page in the docs.